# How to increase the height of header in table view according to the text increasing in label taken in stackview in swift4?

Tags: swift

I have taken a `UILabel` whose content is to be increased whose initial number of lines is 2 then on `UIButton` click it is increased to 0. Sometimes the height of header increases accurately but otherwise, it increases to a great extent by using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will help you**

- You can get Label Height using below function

  ```
  func heightForLabel(text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

      let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
      label.numberOfLines = 0
      label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
      label.font = font
      label.text = text
      label.sizeToFit()

      return label.frame.height
  }
  ```
- UITableView Header Method

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        let height = self.heightForLabel(text: 'your text', font: 'font which you in label' , width: 'your label width')
        return height //return height for label.
  }
  ```